# Django: Calculating Delta on Tables

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-1.4

I have two tables in a Postgres database with identical structure and partly overlapping data, call them `table1` and `table2`. I'm trying to calculate the delta by getting all the rows that are in one table but not the other. The queries I'm trying to run are roughly this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
```

What is the best way to structure this in Django 1.4? Is there some way I can just have one model defined for both tables? What is the best way to query this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a base table:

```
class Table(models.Model):
   #some fields
   pass

class Table1(Table):
   #some fields specific for table 1
   pass

class Table2(Table):
   #some fields specific for table 2
   pass
```

To obtain the table delta you may use:

```
Table1.objects.exclude(id__in=Table2.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
```